# How to gain speed by jumping?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When ever I play this map surf_ski_2_go I always see these guys jump, and when they do jump they get this amazing amount of speed just from jumping. I was wondering how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

What they are doing is called **bhop**. In order to do so, you have to jump and strafe while on the air and then repeat untill you get the speed you want.

In surf maps, you'll see a lot of people doing this but not just to gain more speed, but to **prestrafe**, this means having more speed than normal when starting the timer. It's not as simple as bhopping and landing on a ramp though and this technique is mostly used by pro surfers in order to beat their times.

Answer (score 1):

They don't get the speed from jumping. In fact they aren't jumping at all. The speed is gained by surfing on slopes and using gravity to accelerate down a slope. Bigger distances are gained once leaving the slope as a result of gaining more speed whilst on the slope.

Comment: that's not what he is asking for.

Comment: @Alex Could you elaborate on what the OP *is* asking, perhaps by suggesting an edit on the original question to clarify?

Comment: @Alex looks like a surf map to me: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=128088054

Comment: @Shadur OP is asking how they do to gain speed by jumping, not by surfing on the map ramps.

Comment: @Tanner it is a surf map, though OP is not asking how they gain speed by surfing, but jumping (bhopping)

Comment: @Alex I've simply assumed that as it was a surf map he was saying "jumping" for when players are leaving a ramp. Either way, both answers could be valid unless he clarifies.

Comment: I am honestly thinking about casting a flag for "Unclear of what you are asking" for this question since without further information nobody can figure out what he is talking about in particular.

Comment: @Ramirez yeah would make sense, it's pretty unclear considering the debate we've had over it.

Comment: OP does say "just from jumping," which makes me think it is about bunny hopping since there are no mentions of slopes or ramps. I would still say the question is unclear due to the limited information he provides.

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to get such speed in normal games. What you are seeing is one of the main mechanics of Surf maps. These types of maps completely change the game by making obstacle course which require high amounts of precision and speed in order to pass certain parts of the stage.

These maps and servers work by increasing the value of sv_airaccelerate beyond the default value of 10 to around 150 or 1000 on some servers. This command changes how quickly a player can turn without losing speed. When playing these maps to gain speed on ramps you need to hold  <kbd>A</kbd>  or <kbd>D</kbd> plus holding  <kbd>W</kbd>  depending on which way the ramp is facing. This allows you to pick up speed in order to perform the tricks the map requires.

Source: [Information on surfing](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Surfing) (TF also uses the Source game engine.)

Comment: first of all, as said before, he is not asking how to surf, but how do players get speed by jumping, which is called bhop and, when done on a surf server, pre-strafing (it's the same just with a different goal than just bhopping)

Comment: The question is extremely vague, I don't honestly think he would have mentioned the surf map if it didn't relate to surf map. If he was mentioning people jumping constantly then yes I would assume bunny hopping is what he is asking about. But since most surf maps do require a jump before actually starting to slide surfing seems more feasible than bunny hopping.

Comment: that's because they are not just bhopping, but prestrafing, which both look exactly the same if you don't know what they are doing. + he literally says *"and when they do jump they get this amazing amount of speed"* and that looks like he is implying that they have to jump to get more speed.

Comment: I understand that, the question is still extremely vague though @Alex since *"and when they do jump they get this amazing amount of speed"* could refer to leaving the ramp after surfing. I am actually just going to flag this question as *"Unclear of what you are asking*" since both are valid answers without more context.

Comment: and just as a side note, never recommend pressing W when surfing, that's only used for sideways surfing, which is way harder than regular one :D